# Adding a want answers feature

Tags: feature-request

Not sure whether this seems a valid question.Suppose someone has posted a question and i am also very interested in knowing the answer of that question. WHy cant we have a feature which says "notify me when someone answers" and if wanted we can be notified through email..

Comment: This is a Q&A Site, so an Answer is expected.  In addition you can Favorite the Question.

Comment: I mean to say i want to get notified when someone answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "favourite questions" thing had, for a brief period, notifications on changes. It was shortly  removed, and has shown no signs of coming back in the four years since.

See [Jeff Atwood's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52094/270345).

Comment: So currently the only notifier is the app

Comment: @Virusboy you can get digest emails of inbox notifications, and emails of new questions via tag filters, but that's about it, i think.

Comment: I believe there are still RSS feeds for questions though.

Comment: @Seth individual questions?

Comment: @muru yes, in the bottom right corner of the screen, under the hot questions. For example, for this post: http://meta.askubuntu.com/feeds/question/13427

Comment: @Seth excellent. It should possible to use an RSS app or similar service to get notifications then.